# Can a One way function also be its inverse?

Tags: one-way-function, trapdoor

This is from my homework:

- Prove that if there exists a one-way function, then there exists a one-way function f such that

  $f(0^n ) = 0^n$ for every $n$.

  Note that now for infinitely many values $y$, it is trivial to compute $f^{−1}(y)$.

While I don't expect someone to spell the answer out for me, setting f as the inverse function, we can say the inverse exists. As a result, it is not a one-way function.

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography. For Homeworks we only provide hints. However, It is not clear what do you mean by ` f(0 n ) = 0 n`. **Note**: You can use $LaTeX$/MathJax in out site.

Answer (score 1):

One-way function doesn't mean that it's impossible to reverse EVERY output.
One-way function means that's it's hard to invert on an output picked at random over the set of the outputs.

In the standard definition, the challenger picks an input $x$ uniformly at random, and the adversary receives an image of $x$ by the function.

You can read in more details the definitions given in [the following link](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/crypto/oneway.html).

Comment: Please see [Our current homework policy](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1115/do-we-want-to-update-the-way-we-handle-homework-questions/1117#1117)

Comment: The question was not about how to solve the exercise, the homework was just the context about the question (If I didn't misunderstood).

Comment: "hard to invert on an output picked at random over the set of the outputs" this statement may lead someone to think that the outputs are sampled uniformly from the range. That's not the case. The output is sampled by sampling *uniformly* from the domain and then applying the function to get an element of the range. While this is still "random" in a reasonable sense of the word, it can deviate quite significantly from a uniform distribution.

Comment: Emphasizing @Maeher's comment, since it is a common misconception. We always sample from a distribution over the domain (else if you sample from the range it might be difficult to sample hard instances, as it requires inverting the output.)